# Ipod Classic 120 GB frozen when syncing with a new PC.

Tags: data-synchronization, performance, ipod-classic

I am trying to sync my Ipod Classic with my new PC, and my iTunes account is the same username, login, etc. My iPod has frozen in the "Connected- Eject before disconnecting" screen. It isn't syncing, and it's not registering on iTunes, but my Spotify application is picking it up. However, the PC doesn't recognize it when I try to "safely eject it" on the bottom taskbar of the desktop/browsing window. I did get one short message from iTunes stating my Ipod is corrupted, but I have gotten this message before and it fixed itself. So right now my iPod is frozen on that "Connected" screen, but it is not registering on iTunes. any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: never mind i reset it. thank you. post can be closed

Comment: On Stack Exchange, it is encouraged to even answer your own question - so perhaps answer with what you did to solve the problem, to help future users...

Comment: I went on to the Apple site, to try to figure out how to reset an iPod. It turns out that if you have a device with a click wheel, you can just flip the "Hold" button at the top on and then off again, and after that hold the "up" and "menu" buttons for 6-8 seconds until you see the Apple logo. It worked perfectly, and all my music was still on the iPod as well!

Answer (score 1):

Let your iPod connected to your PC then turn the pc off by clicking "turn off computer" good Luck!

Herchixnyc